# React Native- Updating the state value automatically when the new record inserts in database

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native-paper for the BottomNavigation and my BottomNavigation code is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import AccountList from './AccountList.js';
import Calendar from './calendar.js';
import MapView from './map.js';
import { BottomNavigation, Text } from 'react-native-paper';
// import AgendaScreen from './calendar.js';

const AccountRoute = () => {
    return (
      <AccountList/>
   )
};

const ScheduleRoute = () => {
  return (
    <Calendar/>
 )
};

const TerritoryRoute = () => {
  return (
    <MapView/>
 )
};

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: 'account', title: 'Account', icon: 'people'},
      { key: 'schedule', title: 'Schedule', icon: 'date-range'},
      { key: 'territory', title: 'Territory', icon: 'assessment'},
    ],
  };

  _handleIndexChange = (index) => {
      console.log(index)
      this.setState({ index : index});
      // if (index===1){
      //   this.refs.AgeRef._fetchscheduedaccount()
      // }
  }

  _renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
    account: AccountRoute,
    schedule: ScheduleRoute,
    territory: TerritoryRoute,
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <BottomNavigation
        labeled = 'false' 
        navigationState={this.state}
        onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
        barStyle={{backgroundColor:'#0297E3'}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

In my calendar component I am setting the state value of scheduledrepdata by fetching the api data in componentdidmount function:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch('http://www.example.com')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
        scheduledrepdata: responseJson,
        })

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

/* In my AccountList component I am inserting new record in the database */

```
  fetch("http://www.example.com", {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                schedule_date: '2019-08-07',
                sales_rep_id :1,
                ims_id: 123,
              })
          })

    .then((responseJson) => {
      /* Do Something */
      })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error value',error);

      });
```

When I click back on the calendar component through bottom navigation I want that in the scheduledrepdata the recently inserted records should also be displayed .

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the event of coming back (Focus) to the screen that you want to update. You could do that with react-navigation, and `addListener` `didFocus` event:

> `addListener` - Subscribe to updates to navigation lifecycle
>
> React Navigation emits events to screen components that subscribe to
>   them:
>
> 1. `willBlur` - the screen will be unfocused
> 2. `willFocus` - the screen will focus
> 3. `didFocus` - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the
>      transition completed)
> 4. `didBlur` - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the
>      transition completed)

An easy example, first on `componentDidMount()`

```
 componentDidMount(){
    // we generate the listener on the screen we want to update on focus back
    this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.onFocusBack)
  }
```

Then the function that is binded to the listener:

```
onFocusBack = () => {
    // Here you call your fetch to retry new data and mutate the state of the component
  }
```

Comment: What is this.props.navigation here ? Can you please explain this with example